# linked list union

Tags: c++

In my "void union" function I am unsure how to insert the data from both linked lists "A" and "B" that the user has input respectively since the "AUB" is not within the void function. I would have put:

```
AUB.insert
```

but I was unsure. Any suggestions?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Sets
{
private:struct NODE
        {
            int info;
            NODE *next;
        };
        NODE *list;
public:Sets()
       {
           list=NULL;
       }
       void Insert(int x)
       {
           NODE *p=list, *q=list, *r;
           //create a new node
           r = new (NODE);
           r->info = x;
           r->next = NULL;
           //find the insertion place
           while(p != NULL && p->info < x)
           {
               q=p;
               p=p->next;
           }
           if(p==list)//x is the first info
           {
               list=r;
               r->next=p;
           }
           else if(p==NULL)//x is the last info
           {
               q->next=r;
           }
           else //x is neither forst nor last info
           {
               r->next=p;
               q->next=r;
           }
       }
        void display()
        {
            NODE *p=list;
            while(p != NULL)
            {
                cout << p->info << "-->";
                p=p->next;
            }
            cout << "NULL\n";
        }
        void Union(Sets setA,Sets setB)
        {
            NODE *p=setA.list, *q=setB.list;
            while(p != NULL && q != NULL)
            {
                if(p->info > q-> info)
                {
                    (q->info)
                    q=q->next;
                }
                else if(p->info == q->info)
                {
                    insert(p->info)
                    p=p->next;
                    q=q->next;
                }
                else//P->info < q->info
                {
                    insert(p->info);
                    p=p->next;
                }
            }
            while(p !=NULL)
            {
                insert(p->info);
                p=p->next;
            }
            while(q != NULL)
            {
                insert(q->info);
                q=q->next;
            }
        }
};


int main()
{   
    //create a set of integers
    int x;
    Sets A, B, setAUB;
    cout << "Enter data for setA:\n";
    cout << "Enter a group of positive integer numbers with -1 at the end end: ";
    cin >> x;
    while(x != -1)
    {
        A.Insert(x);
        cin >> x;
    };
    //display setA
    cout << endl << "setA=";
    A.display();

    cout << "Enter data for setB:\n";
    cout << "Enter a group of positive integer numbers with -1 at the end end: ";
    cin >> x;
    while(x != -1)
    {
        B.Insert(x);
        cin >> x;
    };
    //display setB
    cout << endl << "setB=";
    B.display();

    setAUB.Union(A, B);
    //display setAUB
    cout << endl << "setAUB=";
    setAUB.display();

    system ("pause");

    //terminate program
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: `void Union()` is one bad name for an function.You should change it to something meaningful.

Comment: Could you elaborate? The functions purpose is to combine both A and B

Comment: union is a keyword for defining "unions", this might lead to false assumptions when you define a functinon that differs from the keyword by the capital letter only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define it: `void Union(Sets setA,Sets setB)`.

What are you doing? Both passed by value, and the return value is `void` - where does the result go?

Does your current object (`this` in the `Union` function) become that union? If so, what happens to the data already in it? You're not deleting it, so you're basically merging three sets, not two...

I would suggest to create a **static** `merge` function that would take the two parameters and *return* a **new** list which would be the merge of the two.

Otherwise, create a regular `merge` function, that would only take 1 parameter, and merge it into the current object.

By the way - why `Sets`, when it is obviously a sorted linked list?

Comment: 1.I have passed values of setA and setB into the function, I use p and q to point to those blocks and thats where the results go. 2.Ignore the third set and I have deleted it. 3.Sets is just shorter than orderedlinkedlist!

Comment: @SeanFlores I didn't understand #1 and #2, what I wrote was with regards to the code you posted. Re #3 - *set* is **not** a *list*. These terms are very well defined, and you're giving them meaning that they don't have (in eyes of others). If its a *list* - don't call it *set*.